# gcc wont find sqrt even with -lm parameter

Tags: c, math, gcc, makefile

I am using sqrt in my .c file and including math.h for this.
When compiling it with the -lm flag it still prompts me with "undefined reference to `sqrt'"

How is this supposed to be solved?

Comment: Put the `-lm` flag at the *end* of the command line.

Comment: What is the exact command line you're using? More than likely it's solvable with what KerrekSB said, but we can't know for sure

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with `-Wall` to see if there are any warnings?